# Laravel связь один ко многим

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть связь один ко многим

```
$userMessages = $user->messages;
```

она возвращает объект сообщений конкретного пользователя вида

```
 [{id: 1, city_id: 1, user_id: 1, name: null, email: null, phone: null, title: "sdcsdv",…},…]
0: {id: 1, city_id: 1, user_id: 1, name: null, email: null, phone: null, title: "sdcsdv",…}
city_id: 1
created_at: "2020-01-19 11:23:07"
email: null
id: 1
message: "sdvsdv"
name: null
phone: null
show: false
title: "sdcsdv"
updated_at: "2020-01-19 11:23:07"
user_id: 1
1: {id: 2, city_id: 1, user_id: 1, name: null, email: null, phone: null, title: "sdcsdvsdv",…}
2: {id: 4, city_id: 1, user_id: 1, name: null, email: null, phone: null, title: "scasc", message: "as",…}
```

Первый объъект тут развернут для наглядность.

Мне нужно получить только дату последнего сообщения created_at.

Как мне лучше это сделать, через foreach? Есть ли какие то менее затратные способы?

Answer (score -1):

$last = Message::query()->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->latest()->first();

Comment: Почти. Так более правильно: optional($user->messages()->latest()->first())->created_at;

Comment: `optional` хэлпер для того, чтобы не вылетело исключение, если сообщений нет